# Cannot convert lambda expression to type ‘System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Action>’ because it is not a delegate type. error in hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(“sqlcn”);

    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine(“Hello”), Cron.Minutely());

    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseHangfireServer();
}
```

In this code, I have this error:-
Cannot convert lambda expression to type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Action>` because it is not a delegate type.
Please Help Me.!

Comment: This code is correct as it is, I don't think the issue is related to this snippet. Maybe check out [this](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-applications.html) and make sure that you set it up the same way in your code.

Comment: What's the hangfire version?

Comment: Since your posted code has invalid quote characters, please double-check and post the _exact_ code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine(“Hello”), Cron.Minutely());
```

to this:

```
var action = () => Console.WriteLine(“Hello”), Cron.Minutely();
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(action);
```

I've seen those problems when applying directly.